# Единая строка навигации для всех вкладок tab view controller

Tags: objective-c, xcode, storyboard, navigationcontroller

Имею storyboard в которой в корне navigation controller. Так же в карте storyboard использую tab bar controller. Необходимо подменить кнопки в navigation bar во всех tab bar item. Возможно ли это сделать сразу для всех вкладок tab bar controller, так как navigation bar предполагает будет одинаковая для всех tab bar controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, можно. Это делается созданием подкласса, то есть вы создаете CustomTabBarController и задаете ему те иконки, которые вам нужны. Потом просто используете не UITabBarController, а свой tab bar. Очень часто это приходится делать, когда, например, есть приложение, и по дизайну каждый экран похож на предыдущий (кнопка назад везде одинакова и т.д.), и тогда создается просто BaseViewController и в нем пишется вся логика по дизайну, и уже создавая новые контроллеры, вы наследуетесь не от UIViewController, а от BaseViewController.